# How to identify proxy model instances?

Tags: django, proxy

I need to create several types of users with different permissions.

I'm trying to do so using proxy, but I'm not sure how to identify the resulting instances. I know that using proxy the models are in the same table in the DB, but I need to be able to identify them. For instance in the `MyUser` list in the admin I have all the instances created from `User` and `MyUser` model, and I'd like to have only `MyUser` instances.

I guess I should override the `queryset` method in `MyUser` admin, but I'm not sure what's the best way to identify `MyUser` instances, or even if it's the right way to have several user models with different permissions.

Anybody could help?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

**admin.py**

```
class MyUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(MyUser, MyUserAdmin)
```

Comment: Why not just use Groups to assign the permissions?

Comment: I'd like to have them separate in my admin, and this was the easiest way I could see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a group `myusers`, and add it to the instance when creating a `MyUser` object, so that I can filter them out in `MyAdminUser` queryset:

```
class MyUser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='myusers'))
```